# How to change output text conditionally

Tags: jsf, label, conditional-rendering

I have a supplier table with column `gst_invoice_type`. The table have two rows, with value F and S.

In my PrimeFaces dataTable, I also created a table with column `Gst_Invoice_Type` with drop down menu filter as below code

```
<p:column filterBy="#{vo.gstInvoiceType}" headerText="GST Invoice Type." sortBy="#{vo.gstInvoiceType}"
                        style="width:130px;" visible="false">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:selectOneMenu style="width:110px; vertical-align:middle;" autoWidth="false"
                        onchange="PF('varTable').filter()">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Full Tax Invoice" itemValue="F" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Simplified Invoice" itemValue="S" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{vo.gstInvoiceType}"/>
                </p:column>
```

When select All, all data (F and S) will be retrieved and located in Gst_Invoice_Type, which working correctly. But is it possible to let the F and S display as Full Tax Invoice and Simplified Invoice ?

Comment: Sorry, i do not get it. Please explain what you want or what the problem is in more detail.

Comment: @irieill OK. I have value `F` and `S` in MySQL. Is there a way to let the F display as Full Tax Invoice and S display as Simplified Invoice in primeFaces dataTable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simply** insert two conditionally rendered `<h:outputText />` elements with different values.

```xml
<p:column>
  <h:outputText
    value="Full Tax Invoice"
    rendered="#{vo.gstInvoiceType eq 'F'}"
  />
  <h:outputText
    value="Simplified Invoice"
    rendered="#{vo.gstInvoiceType eq 'S'}"
  />
</p:column>
```

**Another option** is to do the mapping programmatically in a bean method like:

```xml
<p:column>
  <h:outputText value="#{bean.map(vo.gstInvoiceType)}" />
</p:column>
```

with

```java
public class Bean {
  public String map(String input) {
    // however you implement your mapping
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks,but if I have a case with 100 rows, and some column contains empty,will your answer work ?

Comment: @AI. Sure it will work (with more effort in writing down the code for the different cases).